# My conjecture: $\Delta(m,\theta,a)<0\text{ if and only if }a\in (\underline{a},\overline{a})$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

Consider two real-valued function $\phi $ and $\Delta$, defined as \begin{equation*}
 \phi (m,\theta ,j,a)=\frac{m-1}{\left( j+(m-1)\theta \right)
  ^{a}}-\frac{m+1 }{\left( j+m\theta \right) ^{a}}\text{,}
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} \Delta(m,\theta,a)=\left( \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\theta }\phi (m,\theta
 ,j,a)\right) -\left( \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\theta +1}\phi (m,\theta
 +1,j,a)\right) \text{.} \end{equation*}

where $m \in \{2,3,\dots\}, \theta \in \{1,2,\dots\}, j \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, and $a$ is nonnegative real number.

**My conjecture**: For any given $m$ and $\theta $, there exist $\underline{a}=\underline{a}(m,\theta )$ and $\overline{a}=\overline{a} (m,\theta )$ (with $1<\underline{a}<\overline{a}$) such that \begin{equation*} \Delta(m,\theta,a)<0\text{  if  and  only if }a\in (\underline{a},\overline{a})\text{.} \end{equation*}

So far, I have tried many approaches ranging from Taylor's Expansion to Jensen's inequality. None of them worked.

Any comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that there is a typo and the formula of $\phi$ should be
$$ \phi (m,\theta ,j,a)=\frac{m-1}{\left( j+(m-1)\theta \right)
  ^{a}}-\frac{\color{red}{m} }{\left( j+m\theta \right) ^{a}}$$

Comment: @NN2 First of all, thank you for taking the time to take a look at my question. The formula is correct. It is, in fact, m+1, not m. Believe it or not, I have been working on this problem for so long that I will highly appreciate any feedback regarding a possible approach. I have produced many numerical examples, each one supporting my conjecture.

Comment: Could you give some motivation for defining this function? Does it arise in study of some probabilistic distribution?

Comment: @ShengtongZhang Not really. It cropped up in one of my papers, which is in economics, which I have been working on for a while.

Comment: Do you have an advisor or collaborator? It would be better to show your colleague the problem, explain to them why it is important, and motivate them to work hard on this problem(unfortunately, not a lot of people on the internet are willing to seriously work on a problem, especially one that don't look interesting to them.)

Comment: @ShengtongZhang Thank you for your advice.